# Enclosing text inside a circle and adding a small caption to the circle(HTML / CSS)

Tags: html, css

I am new to html and css and I am trying figure out how to build shapes using html and css.

I would like to put two line text in a circle and add a small caption to that circle as shown below,
[image]

I want to align 6 of such circles in a two row table(each row 3 cells). Each cell in the table will be a circle (with two lines text inside) and with a small description above it.

Could someone please help me on how to go about doing this?

Thank You.

Comment: Can you please the code you have done so far ?

Answer (score 2):

This can be done using CSS.

HTML Code:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Description
            <div class="circle">Circle 1 <br> cirlce 2</div>
        </td>
        <td>
            Description
            <div class="circle">Circle 1 <br> cirlce 2</div>
        </td>
        <td>
            Description
            <div class="circle">Circle 1 <br> cirlce 2</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Description
            <div class="circle">Circle 1 <br> cirlce 2</div>
        </td>
        <td>
            Description
            <div class="circle">Circle 1 <br> cirlce 2</div>
        </td>
        <td>
            Description
            <div class="circle">Circle 1 <br> cirlce 2</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS Code:

```
<style>
.circle
{
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    border-radius:25px;
    font-size:9px;
    color:#fff;
    line-height: 25px;
    text-align:center;
    background:#000
}
table tr td {
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center
}
</style>
```

Working example: [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rL6psmxf/)

Update Fiddle: [New Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rL6psmxf/1/)

Comment: Also remember that you can use the eyedropper in almost any graphic design tool (Photoshop anyone?) to get the hexadecimal number on the color scheme you want.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I was wondering if it is possible to align the text inside the circle at the center of the circle.

Comment: @Ranger if this answer helps you please accept it so that future reader will get correct answer to your problem.

Comment: I want the two text to start at the centre of the circle. Could you please tell me how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

try this.I wrote a code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>fade effect</title>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
 <style type="text/css">
  body{
   margin: 0;
  }

div.mycircle{
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 50px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(blue,white);
  color: black;
  border-radius: 250px;
 
}

 </style>

<body>

<div class="mycircle">
  <span style="position: absolute; top: 250px;left: 250px;font-size: 30px;">Line 1</span>
  <span style="position: absolute; top: 280px;left: 250px;font-size: 30px;">Line 2</span>
</div>
  


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Read about CSS rules called: border-radius, padding, line-height, text-align and background-color.

You can do so [here](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/) ;)